# Remove short words and characters from a string Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Input string:

```
String input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
```

Output string:

```
String output = "Lorem Ipsum simply dummy printing typesetting industry";
```

What is the best way to remove short words?

Here my first idea:

```
private String removeShortWords(String string){
    int minLength = 5;
    String result = "";

    String[] words = string.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        String word = words[i];
        if(word.length() >= minLength){
            result += word + " ";
        }
    }       

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Define 'short'. Is the aim to remove any word with less than 5 chars?

Comment: I recommend using `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One line:

```
String output = input.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,4}\\b\\s?", "");
```

Comment: It would make "Can't believe it" => "Can believe it"

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine except that:

- You don't preserve number of spaces when you rebuild the String.
- You should use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `+=`.
- You add redundant space at the end.

I would do something like that:

Iterate on the String, as long as I have a `char`, I increment a counter and add the char to some temp String, otherwise, I have a space. I check the value of the counter, if it's `<= 5` I don't add the temp String, otherwise, I do. This way I preserve the spaces too.

Regarding the complexity, it's O(n) when `n` is the length of the String, as we "travel" on the String only once.

Answer (score 1):

You approach is ok, but for performance reasons it is better to use use StringBuilder, as the `+=` creates it in every iteration of the loop. Notice also Maroun's comments regarding the integrity of the output.

Another option is to use regular expression, this call should have the same effect:

```
return string.replaceAll("\\b\\w{1,4}\\b","");
```

Notice that for performance reasons you would want to pre-comile the pattern and re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

## try this code

```
          String input = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry";
            String[] dev=input.split(" ");
             for(int i=0;i<dev.length;i++)
              if(dev[i].length()<=2)
               input=input.replaceAll(dev[i], "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a StringTokenizer instead of Split and use a StringBuilder to create result

```
int minLength = 5;
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, " ");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
    if(token.length() >= minLength){
    builder.append(token);
        builder.append(" ");
  }
}
return builder.toString();
```